# when allowsEditing is turned on, is there a way to detect the push of the shutter/capture button?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

For the UIImagePickerController, if the allowsEditing flag is turned on, the view will move to Move and Scale view once the picture is taken. My question is, is there a way to detect the pushing of the shutter/capture button and then do something, before the Move and Scale view appears. There is no UIImagePickerController delegate available from what investigated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

technically you could perform an action when a picture is taken if you set your own overlay so that you can use your own button  to do your action and call the take photo method from the uiimagepickercontroller.

Other than that you would have to use avfoundation.

Comment: i think it's basically a question of how to detect the touch of a button on the screen. i still want to give it try on that direction instead of looking for an overlay solution. i will look into avfoundation a little.